# counting issue with NS Managed object and NS ARRAY

Tags: iphone

I am trying to count the number of objects in my core data , so that I can tell how many rows are needed my table view controller, but I am stuck with counting of NS ARRAY, here is the code

```
          NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Data"   inManagedObjectContext:context];
         NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                            ascending:YES
                             selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *temp=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

I am doing it in Data class(sub class of nsmanged object), the issue is when I reach

```
NSLog(@"%@",[temp count]);
```

I get ‘Program received signal:”EXC_BAD_ACCESS”’
I dnt get what is wrong, I am putting my data into a ns array and than trying to count them . help in this regard will be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[temp count] return a number  , not a string

so you need

```
NSLog(@"%u",[temp count]);
```

[look at this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: i cant believe i over looked it , it such a small but yet critical mistake . thanks man